# xsl version 2.0 in JDK 13?

Tags: java, xslt, apache-fop, java-13

I'm trying to use XSL Version 2.0 with openJDK 13 & apache FOP.

Despite having coded the following in the Stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
```

...

```
<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/>
```

...is returning "1.0"

How can I get XSL Version 2.0 running in this environment?

Comment: Put Saxon 9 or 10 HE (available on Sourceforge and Maven) on the class path, I suppose. Unless JDK 13 has breaking changes that don't allow running Saxon 9 or 10 developed for JDK 8. I have tested Saxon 10.1 HE to run with JDK 11, no idea whether JDK 13 breaks some backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way in the Java environment to have XSLT 2 or these days XSLT 3 support is to put Saxon 9 or Saxon 10 HE on the class path. Saxon HE is available on SourceForge or Maven. I think the releases 9.8, 9.9 and 10 all target Java 8 but should run as well with later Java JREs and JDKs as these maintain backwards compatibility.

Comment: Thanks, I pulled in Saxon 10 HE from Maven and - touch wood - seems to work ok with openJDK 13.